# I calculated a complex Fourier series and got this result: $\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\frac{-(-1)^k -1}{(k^2-1)}e^{ikt}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I calculated a complex Fourier series and got this result:
$$
\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\frac{-(-1)^k -1}{(k^2-1)}e^{ikt}.
$$

However, since this is the Fourier series of an absolute value function, I was told I needed to define the series both for $+(k^2-1)$ and $-(k^2-1)$. Moreover, I'm confused about what to do about the case when $k = +1$ or $-1$, since that makes the denominator $0$.

I am extremely new to this difficult topic so any help is appreciated, and sorry if I was unclear.

The formula used for the coefficients: $c_k = \frac{1}{\pi}  \int_0^\pi f(t)e^{-ikt}\,dt$.

Comment: What specific function is this supposed to be the Fourier series of?

Comment: |sin(x)|*e^(-ikt)

Comment: How did you evaluate the coefficients?

Comment: And this is over [0, pi].

Comment: c_k = 1/pi * Integral(f(t)*e^(-ikt))dt

Comment: I suppose I meant, did you evaluate the integrals by hand? You may find you used the wrong antiderivative/had a substitution issue when $k = \pm 1$.

Comment: I did evaluate them by hand and was told this was the right result.

Answer (score 1):

The general formula you have for the coefficients is correct (i.e. $c_k = -\frac{(-1)^k+1}{k^2-1}$). As for the $k=\pm 1$ case, since there is (a priori) a problem with division by zero, the solution is to just solve the relevant integrals by hand, using the fact that $|\sin(t)|$ is nonnegative on $[0,\pi]$:
$$
c_{\pm1} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi |\sin(t)|e^{\mp it} dt = \frac1\pi \int_0^\pi\sin(t)e^{\mp it}dt = \frac1\pi\left.\left(-\frac{e^{\mp2 it}}4 \mp \frac{it}{2}\right)\right|_{t=0}^\pi = \mp\frac i2.
$$
When you evaluate the sum for different values of $n$, you'll see that the $c_{\pm1}$ contributions cancel. But this corresponds to the odd terms vanishing in the general formula, so it may be helpful to reindex the general series so that you're only summing over the even terms.

Comment: Thank you, this part is now clear to me. Could you also explain what I should do with the denominator +-(k^2-1)? Is it somehow related to this point?

Comment: I'm not sure what was meant when you were told the $\pm$ thing. Maybe they meant that you should split into the positive $k$ and negative $k$ cases? At any rate, your expression is correct (once you account for the $k = \pm 1$ terms in my answer)--try plotting a few partial sums if you're unsure.